# Angular2 Promise to Async/Await

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

How can I transform this code ( Promise ):

```
registerUser(formData) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(formData.email,formData.passwords.password)
            .then((user) => {
                firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}`).set({
                    id: user.uid,
                    email: formData.email
                })
                this.routing.navigate(['/login']);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error); 
            })
}
```

Into this one ( async / await ):

```
async registerUser(formData){
    try{
        await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(formData.email,formData.passwords.password);
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}`)
            .set({id: user.uid,email: formData.email});
        this.routing.navigate(['/login']);
        return true;
    }catch(error){
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I get `user.uid` ( which is the registered user uid )? In promises it's so easy, because i just have to pass argument (user) to then. 
Thanks, for help: )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get `user.uid`...

`user` is returned by the `await` expression, so add `let user =` (or `const user =`) in front of it:

```
async registerUser(formData){
    try{
        const user = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(formData.email,formData.passwords.password);
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}`)
            .set({id: user.uid,email: formData.email});
        this.routing.navigate(['/login']);
        return true;
    }catch(error){
        return false;
    }
}
```